# Php mailer doesn't mail to google apps

Tags: php, email, local

I recently migrated my email accounts from a host to google apps. But since then my php mailer form on the website doesn't working anymore. It seems to keep delivering the email to the old mailbox and does not seem to look up the DNS globally, so it doesn't deliver the email to google apps.

Is there any way to fix this without configuring the smtp online?

EDIt

Let me explain it this way: I am able to read my mails from www.domain.com in my gmail account via google apps. So if i send to jack@domain.com I see it in my gmail overview. But! Mails with my phpmailerform to jack@domain.com are not visible in my gmail, altough I still can see them on my webmail. It somehow recognizes it is the same domain and sends it locally I suppose... That is the thing I want to avoid. Hope it is clear now? :)

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Let me explain it this way: I am able to read my mails from www.domain.com in my gmail account via google apps. So if i send to jack@domain.com I see it in my gmail overview. But! Mails with my phpmailerform to jack@domain.com are not visible in my gmail, altough I still can see them on my webmail. It somehow recognizes it is the same domain and sends it locally I suppose... That is the thing I want to avoid. Hope it is clear now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the MX records on your server for that domain so that it knows to deliver the email to google and not to localhost.

Comment: I found the MX entry and changed it! It does the trick, very nice, was searching for this :) Thanks for helping me out @John !

Comment: where did you find them?